# Information criterion with penalty to condition number of hessian matrix?

Tags: model-selection, multinomial-distribution, multicollinearity

I am working on a multinomial logistic model. I have the following questions:

1. AIC is asymptotically same as cross-validation, right? is it also true for logistic model? (N ~= 6000, p ~= 20)
2. I perform a forward stepwise regression to my data using the formula for AIC=2k-2log(L) and select the one with lowest AIC in every step.

   At some point, I am facing a hessian with condition number of the order 10^6 when doing Newton-Raphson method to maximize the loglikelihood function. I believe the procedure select a predictor variable that are highly-correlated to the current best one. I think it is bad and make my computation errors/unstable because of the precision of double-floating number and sometimes I will get a non positive-definite hessian matrix.

   Are there a "modification" to AIC that will add a penality to the condition number so that I could apply when doing forward stepwise regression?
3. I know that the error between a forward stepwise regression to the subset selection is related to the covariance matrix of those predictor variables, am I working in a wrong way to use forward stepwise when my predictor variables are highly-correlated?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand item 2, in every "step" you are trying to add variables one at a time to your model and evaluate AIC for each. If that is correct, then k stays the same within the "step", so only the 2nd term of AIC is important. We see that AIC may help select the right number of variables in the model, but not the specific model.
May I recommend L1-regularized logistic regression as a way of subset selection. There is no shortage papers or software; here's a good place to start: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/l1_glmnet/long-glmnet.pdf

Covariance matrix indeed determines the Hessian in the linear regression case; in logistic case it's more complicated. Anyway, regularization should take care of the degenerating Hessian.